# Django's Template Does Not Exist

Tags: python, django, web-deployment

[image]

I got an error which is a template that does not exist while I was created a template folder that contains a file. I had done necessary changes in setting.py file.

[image]

Comment: Show us your definition of `BASE_DIR` and show us where you call the template. Note that you didn't create a django app, but are putting your code directly in the main project folder, which is a bit strange. Did you do the django tutorial?

Answer (score 1):

This should be the hierarchy of your project. Django detects templates like this:

```
manage.py
project_name/
        wsgi.py
        urls.py
        settings.py        
        web/
           urls.py
           models.py
           views.py
           templates/
                     web/ 
                        home.html
                        newhome.html
```

For further info, checkout documentation : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/intro/tutorial03/

Answer (score 0):

You should move your `templates` directory to the root of the project, besides `manage.py`

Basically, thee `BASE_DIR` is where your manage.py file lives; you add `os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')` into your templates directories, meaning one level up.

Answer (score 0):

on your Templates setting,remove the catalog and edit to this

```
os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates')
```